# Probability Density Function sign problem when using Call Price

Tags: local-volatility, calculation

Given the call price $C_t = e^{-\int_t^Tr(s)ds}\int (s-K)^{+}\phi_{S_T}(T,s)ds $

we know that $$\frac{dC}{dK}=-e^{-\int_t^Tr(s)ds}\int_K^{\infty} \phi_{S_T}(T,s)ds$$

Now when I use dirac delta function property $ \int f(t)\delta(t-T)dt = f(T)  $when taking the second derivative with respect to $K$ I find an akward sign minus which I don't know where my calclulus is wrong :

$$\frac{d^2}{dK^2}C=-e^{-\int_t^Tr(s)ds}\int \frac {d}{dK} H(s-K) \phi_{S_T}(T,s)ds$$

with $H$ the heavy side function, which gives : 
$$\frac{d^2}{dK^2}C= -e^{-\int_t^Tr(s)ds}\int \delta(s-K) \phi_{S_T}(T,s)ds $$

$$\frac{d^2}{dK^2}C= -e^{-\int_t^Tr(s)ds}\phi_{S_T}(T,K)$$

and the right result should be without the minus sign here. Where did I go wrong? I know how to find the right result using just the indicator function, but I wanna use the delta function property here to derive it. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that with $H(\cdot)$ the Heaviside function
$$\frac{d}{ds} H(s-K) = \delta(s-K)$$
but 
$$\frac{d}{dK} H(s-K) = \color{red}{-}\delta(s-K)$$

You can also use the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) to write that
$$ \frac{d}{dK} \int_K^\infty \phi_{S_T}(T,s) ds = -\phi(S_T,K) $$

Answer (score 1):

Just the chain rule;

$\frac{d}{dK} H \left (S-K\right)=\delta \left (S-K\right) \frac{d}{dK} \left (S-K\right)=-\delta \left (S-K\right) $